# How can I connect my index in list with for

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, concatenation

I have problem and don't know how to do it.

I concated 2 int collections in 1. First collection was like 1,3,5,6 and second was like 100,200,500,600.

When I concate them they are written like this 1,3,5,6,100,200,500,600.

I need to make them like first member from 1 first collection and first member from second collection.

To write them like this:

```
some text 1 some text 100
some text 3 some text 200
```

I'm not sure if I can do it with for/foreach loop and how I should do It.

Ill try to explain better: You have 2 lists of integer. They are both same lenght. Lenght depends of how many numbers user input. I want to make them look like    First member of list1    and first member of list 2     and to do that for all inputed numbers.  After that i want to sort them by value of list2 from highest value to lowest.   But im not sure if i need to concat them first or i can do it with 2 separeted lists?

Comment: Are you working with collections of well known length?

Comment: Nope its unknow lenght List<int>

Comment: but you almost know that the two lists have the same length, correct?

Comment: Yes they must have same lenght.

Comment: (try using a spelling checker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your hints in the comments, this code should work

```
int[] array1 = {1,3,5,6 };
            int[] array2 = { 100, 200, 500, 600 };

            for (int i=0; i < array1.Length; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array1[i] +" text "+ array2[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro;) <3 Thats it!

Answer (score -1):

User input numbers(as string ) with no limit to int list 1. Than user input numbers(as string) with limit of list 1 inputed numbers and add them to list 2. And then i need to write them out together like (some text ,1. number from list 1, some text, 1 number from list 2 and so on) and i need to order them by descending (by list 2 max value without loosing order)

List 1  (user input 12 ,user input 55,user input 1,user input 303,user input 23.....(unlimited) )

List 2  (user input 100 ,user input 50,user input 300,user input 1000,user input 500.....(limited to list1.count) )

As result i neeed  to be like :   "number" 12  "number" 100
                                  "number" 55   "number" 50
                                  "number" 1    "number" 300
                                    etc...

```
                                and  after all that order them by descending (by list2)
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can read them in or how you can Order them? And please don't post an Answer with a new Question, edit your original question instead!

Comment: Any advice? Please

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you want to do, could you please post a really clear example containing your input and exactly how the output should look like.

Comment: Ill try to explain better: You have 2 lists of integer. They are both same lenght. Lenght depends of how many numbers user input. I want to make them look like    First member of list1    and first member of list 2     and to do that for all inputed numbers.  After that i want to sort them by value of list2 from highest value to lowest.   But im not sure if i need to concat them first or i can do it with 2 separeted lists?

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please delete it. If you need to add more information to your question then just edit the question. The standard practice is to add more detail to the bottom of the existing question.